# проблема установки php-fpm на Centos7

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

**Доброго времени суток!
Возникла проблема следующего характера:
При установке php-fpm на OC Centos7 выдает следующее**

```
# yum install -y php-fpm php-cli php-mysql php-gd php-ldap php-odbc php-pdo php-pecl-memcache php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-snmp php-soap

Загружены модули: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.colocall.net
* epel: mirrors.colocall.net
* extras: centos.colocall.net
* remi-php71: remi.schlundtech.de
* remi-php72: remi.schlundtech.de
* remi-php73: remi.schlundtech.de
* remi-safe: remi.schlundtech.de
* updates: centos.colocall.net
* webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Пакета с названием php-fpm не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-cli не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-mysql не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-gd не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-ldap не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-odbc не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-pdo не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-pecl-memcache не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-pear не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-xml не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-xmlrpc не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-mbstring не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-snmp не найдено.
Пакета с названием php-soap не найдено.
Ошибка: Выполнять нечего
```

Перед этим установил nginx. И уже была установлена версия php 7.2.20

Может у кого-то было что-то похожее или есть какие-нибудь идеи?!

Answer (score 0):

Ставил php 7.2, 7.3 на centos 6 и 7. Там была какая-то замутка с многоверсионностью php из репозитория remi, подробностей не помню. Остановился на том, что в системе стоит 1 (одна) версия php, которая доступна и в cli, и в apache, и в php-fpm. Добиться такого, как в Ubuntu, - одна версия в апаче, другая в php-fpm, третья в cli - мне не удалось. Если Вас такой вариант устроит, попробуйте удалить установленную версию и установить нужную Вам. Не забудьте отключить репозиторий старой версии после удаления, иначе будет конфликт. Установка как в [инструкции](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-php-7-centos-7-rhel-7-server/) у меня проходила нормально.

P.S. Можно еще попробовать ставить не по php, а как php73 или php72:

`yum install -y php73-fpm php73-cli php73-mysql...`

Идею Вы поняли.

Answer (score 0):

в репозитории remi нужно включить в нужном файле enabled=1. например в файле /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php73.repo

```
[remi-php73]
name=Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/$basearch/
#mirrorlist=https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/httpsmirror
mirrorlist=http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

в остальных файлах напиши enabled=0

тогда при команде  yum install -y php-fpm ... будет устанавливаться версия 7.3

Ну и вообще посмотри что у тебя вообще находит

```
yum search php-fpm
```

у меня например находит:

```
php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php54-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php55-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php56-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php70-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php71-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php72-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php73-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php74-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
zabbix-nginx-conf.noarch : Automatic zabbix frontend configuration with nginx and php-fpm
```